# using a static final variable in SharedPreferance cause memory leak?

Tags: android, performance

I am using a static final String to reference Sharedpreference value like below:

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String KEYCODE_HELP = "keycode_help";
}
```

And using it like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
//put
editor.putInt(Constants.KEYCODE_HELP, 1);
//get
editor.getint(Constants.KEYCODE_HELP);
```

and done this multiple times. Does this cause memory leak?

Comment: Definitely not. It doesn't cause any problem. Meanwhile it's a great way to organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

The static variable gets memory at class loading time only once in the class area.
Making a variable static final will not cause any kind of memory leaks just because it was marked static final. but if you point to an activity, fragment, or view context leak,
it will.

[Application Context](https://miro.medium.com/max/600/1*UfkM21pehBV_V9avkhywmw.png)

for more Infomation, you can see the links

[9 ways to avoid memory leaks in Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/9-ways-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-android-b6d81648e35e)

[Android memory leak with static final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018193/android-memory-leak-with-static-final)

[View the Java heap and memory allocations with Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler)